# Kill child jobs that are running longer than 20 minutes

Tags: bash, shell-script, process, background-process

So I have some processes that run background jobs (resque) on servers and some of those jobs start a child process that occasionally gets stuck. I've found if I kill that child process everything goes back to normal. We have another script that can kill a binary process if it goes to long but it doesn't seem to work here. Usually I can do this:

```
killall --older-than 20m <process>
```

But these workers seem to be a little more tricky. Here is how they look in ps:

```
jbsmith@server:~$ ps aux | grep resque
www-data 17652  0.0  1.8 794148 145940 ?       Sl   11:03   0:05 resque-1.26.0: Processing email since 1494525823 [Email]
www-data  1026  0.0  1.9 787712 157080 ?       Sl   10:47   0:13 resque-1.26.0: Forked 17652 at 1494525823
```

The "Forked x at x" is the child process and the one I need to kill. Is there a one liner command I can use to find processes maybe matching "Forked" and older than 20 minutes and kill them?

Comment: can you run the jobs via `timeout 20m yourjobhere` ?

Comment: well resque launches the process I need to kill so I don't think so... the main parent process is a worker that is always running

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "one-liner", split onto two lines for less scrolling:

```
ps aux | awk -v cutoff=$(( $(date +%s) - 20 * 60 ))  \
  '/resque.*Forked [0-9]+ at [0-9]+/ { if ($NF < cutoff) system("kill " $2) }'
```

It could be made tighter by using an output specifier for `ps` to limit the output to just the PID and COMM and ARG fields, then specifically matching COMM and ARGS, but the risks of a false-positive match seem low to me, here.

Comment: Note: if using this with a cron you have to escape the % so it would be:
    ps aux | awk -v cutoff=$(( $(date +\%s) - 20 * 60 ))  \
  '/resque.*Forked [0-9]+ at [0-9]+/ { if ($NF < cutoff) system("kill " $2) }'